# Fill the value in Textfield using Random number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, auto-populate

I am trying to Populate textbox with random number I am trying it on one textbox currently. On event load i want the textbox to be filled with random number using javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Random() 
      {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      } 
</script>   

<form name="f1">
    a=      <input type="text" name="field1" /></br>
    b=      <input type="text" name="field2" /></br>
    Answer: <input type="text" name="ansfield" />

<input type="button" value="Fill"  onload()="document.getElementById('field1').value=Random()"/>

</form>
```

Comment: `onload()=` is not html conform, try onload= , not sure if onload is supported on input elements, in any way validate your HTML BEFORE you try JS on it

Answer (score 2):

just set the id for html text element , because you are trying to get the value of element by its id ,try this

```
<form name="f1">
    a=      <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" /></br>
    b=      <input type="text" name="field2" /></br>
    Answer: <input type="text" name="ansfield" />

    <input type="button" value="Fill" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('field1').value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<script>` at the end of the HTML and set the field value in that. You are also missing the `id` property of your `input`:

```
<body>
    <form name="f1">
        a=      <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" /></br>
        b=      <input type="text" name="field2" /></br>
        Answer: <input type="text" name="ansfield" />

        <input type="button" value="Fill" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Random() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        }

        document.getElementById('field1').value = Random()
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for replying i tried but not working how to set value?

Comment: @SangramBarge - I made an edit, you were missing the `id` parameter on your `input`

Comment: thanks a lot i got it so setting value means setting by id . I appreciate its working now!